# Running Android Tests with code coverage through Gradle command

Tags: android, testing, gradle, build-automation

Without using JaCoCo, is there a way to run code coverage on my tests through Gradle commands? There does not appear to be a Gradle task which runs tests with coverage on. The only option I see is a button on the Android Studio UI which will run my tests with code coverage.

Ideally I'd like to automate my tests with code coverage from command line and access the report it generates.

By the way, I do not have anything against JaCoCo. I just want to know if there is a way to do this without using the library.

edit: [Possibly related but didn't the solution did not work for me](https://patrickmclaren.com/jacoco-code-coverage-on-android/) - testDebug is not a task for me.

edit 2: [Google Issue Tracker](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=144664) which seems to be related to my question. Opened over a year ago.

edit 3: Appears that this is also an issue when trying to use Jacoco... There does not appear to be a gradle task provided by jacoco to do unit tests in the src/test directory from my research. Would love to be proven wrong!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to solve my problem after much research into how Gradle works and thanks to some examples such as [here](https://plus.google.com/u/0/+OleksandrKucherenko/posts/6vNWkkLed3b) and from this github project [here](https://github.com/serj-lotutovici/jacoco-example/blob/master/build.gradle). I needed to make a few tweaks to get it to work with my project, but the result is that I can run code coverage on JUST my unit tests found in the src/test/ directory from the command line, and access those generated reports.

Here's what the task looks like in my build.gradle:

```
task jacocoReport(type: JacocoReport, dependsOn: 'testMockDebugUnitTest') {
    group = 'Reporting'
    description = 'Generate Jacoco coverage reports after running tests.'

    reports {
        xml.enabled = true
        html.enabled = true
    }

    classDirectories = fileTree(
            dir: 'build/intermediates/classes/test/mock/debug',
            excludes: [
                    '**/R*.class',
                    '**/BuildConfig*'
            ]
    )

    sourceDirectories = files('src/main/java')
    executionData = files('build/jacoco/testMockDebugUnitTest.exec')

    doFirst {
        files('build/intermediates/classes/test/mock/debug').getFiles().each { file ->
            if (file.name.contains('$$')) {
                file.renameTo(file.path.replace('$$', '$'))
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Changes that I needed to make: Running my unit tests alone is done by the gradle task `testMockDebugUnitTest`, and the `jacocoReport` task needed to rely on my unit tests being completed first. The generated build tree for me is a little different, so I hardcoded it in. Execution data that Jacoco relies on is found in the .exec file generated by the `testMockDebugUnitTest` task, which also needs to be defined.

After all is said and done, I can now get code coverage for my unit tests separately from my instrumentation tests through command line.